# How to use FunctionDirective in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I find in Vue3 Type Declaration about `Directive`, it is this

```js
export declare type Directive<T = any, V = any> = ObjectDirective<T, V> | FunctionDirective<T, V>;
```

I believe most people are familiar with `ObjectDirective`

```js
export declare interface ObjectDirective<T = any, V = any> {
    created?: DirectiveHook<T, null, V>;
    beforeMount?: DirectiveHook<T, null, V>;
    mounted?: DirectiveHook<T, null, V>;
    beforeUpdate?: DirectiveHook<T, VNode<any, T>, V>;
    updated?: DirectiveHook<T, VNode<any, T>, V>;
    beforeUnmount?: DirectiveHook<T, null, V>;
    unmounted?: DirectiveHook<T, null, V>;
    getSSRProps?: SSRDirectiveHook;
    deep?: boolean;
}
```

But what's the `FunctionDirective`?

```js
export declare type FunctionDirective<T = any, V = any> = DirectiveHook<T, any, V>;

export declare type DirectiveHook<T = any, Prev = VNode<any, T> | null, V = any> = (el: T, binding: DirectiveBinding<V>, vnode: VNode<any, T>, prevVNode: Prev) => void;
```

I tried to find some useful infomation about it in offical documentation, but no gained.

So who can tell me what's this and how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There [2 ways to declare a Vue directive](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#directive) - using an object syntax, where you declare all the hooks that your directive is interested in and a functional syntax, where you pass a function and that function is used for `mounted` and `updated` hooks

So declaring the directive using:

```js
const hook = (el, binding) => {
  // do some stuff
}

app.directive('my-directive', hook)
```

...is same as:

```js
const hook = (el, binding) => {
  // do some stuff
}

app.directive('my-directive', {
  mounted: hook,
  updated: hook,
})
```